# How to keep previous set session after FOSUSER login in symfony2.6

Tags: php, symfony, session, fosuserbundle

Hello I am working on shopping cart using Symfony2.6 with FOSUSer Bundle.
And I have set session Id with Product id in sessionTable.
Like this :-

```
    $session = $this->get('session');
    $session->start();
    $sessionId = $session->getId(); 


    $sessionTable = new SessionTable();
    $sessionTable->setSessionId($sessionId);
    $sessionTable->setProductId($productId);
    $em->persist($sessionTable);
    $em->flush();
```

Everything is working But When User Login then SessionId destroy.
How I can get old Session Id after login or register ????

Comment: Not really clear what you're looking for? Is it so that if they shop for something, but login later, they'll still have their shopping cart? Also why would you only have a single product in your session table, what if they have more than one product?

Comment: @JasonRoman Yes, This is for Shopping Cart. This session work when you will click any product add to cart then Product will be add in cart. Problem is everything is working fine but when user login or register then session id lost and Cart is empty and need to again add product .

Comment: @Sid same problem here, did you find out what to do?